# python regexp method returns a list with an empty element

Tags: python, regex, types

I am learning how to use regular expressions in python. I am searching for a pattern in a string and returning a value in that string. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
import re

string = '20180515_154457_Trace3_110K_2_data.dpt'
pattern = r'_Trace3_(\d+)K_\d+_data.dpt'
re.search(pattern,  string).groups()
```

The above returns ('110', ). Why doesn't it just return ('110')? Why does it give me a tuple with an empty second element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it give me a tuple with an empty second element?

Nope. That's a tuple with a single element.

`('110')` is a string, whereas `('110',)` is a tuple of one element.

You can always clarify yourself by a simple `type` run:

```
In [1584]: type(('110'))
Out[1584]: str

In [1585]: type(('110',))
Out[1585]: tuple
```

---

As an additional note, the parentheses (`()`) are there just to avoid ambiguity, it would be treated as a tuple without it as well in any unambiguous case:

```
In [1587]: foo = 100,

In [1588]: type(foo)
Out[1588]: tuple
```

Answer (score 2):

The line...

```
('110', )
```

...Is a single-element tuple. This distinguishes it from a parenthesised expression. The trailing comma is part of Python syntax and as I said, it *is* a single element tuple despite how it looks.

If it were just...

```
('110')
```

... this is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

For a tuple to be considered a tuple, it must have the "second" element.

If it were just one element, it would just be the data.

example:

```
>> x = ('test')
>> x
'test'
>> x = ('test',)
>> x
('test', )
```

In your case you can just do:

```
variable = re.search(pattern, string).groups()[0]
```